# ember.js application setup

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, gruntjs

I have downloaded the mvcTodo application from following link and did the setup as per the readme file

https://github.com/trek/ember-todos-with-build-tools-tests-and-other-modern-conveniences

After 'grunt' command, my console displays

> Running "watch" tasks
>
> > waiting

When I open index.html, it does not show the new task textfield. It seems I am missing something. What change do I need to make in index.html to make the application work?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since the MVC project containes a `package.json` file, I guess to be safe you should run `npm install` first.

Hope it helps